# How to exclude transitively included package assets from flutter build?

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter package [flutter_opencc_ffi_web](https://github.com/dolphinxx/flutter_opencc_ffi/tree/main/flutter_opencc_ffi_web), which contains some [JS files](https://github.com/dolphinxx/flutter_opencc_ffi/tree/main/flutter_opencc_ffi_web/assets/opencc). This package is transitively included in another project of mine. When I build a non-web bundle, I'd like to exclude the JS assets(about 1Mb). How can I achieve that?

I've tried the [build_config](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/build_config/README.md), but don't know how to exclude package assets. The following config doesn't work.

build.yaml

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      exclude:
        - assets/opencc/**
        - assets/packages/flutter_opencc_ffi_web/assets/opencc/**
    dependencies:
      flutter_opencc_ffi_web:
        exclude:
          - assets/opencc/**
```